# AS3 bitwise shift 0?

Tags: actionscript-3, bit-shift, bitwise-operators

I came across this in some AS 3.0 code:

```
(duration >> 0)
```

Where duration is a `Number`. I think I know what a [bitwise right shift](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#bitwise_right_shift) does, but what's the point of shifting 0 bits? This happens a few times in the code, I'd like to understand what it does.

Comment: I guess some is guessing how to code, just hammering in what works  :(

Comment: if you show some of the lines around we'll have more to guess from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few reasons for this..

Firstly, multiplication and division is actually quicker in some circumstances
when we use shift left, shift right...

i.e.   the number 1  in binary is   00000001
Shift it left to become 00000010  and it's now 2 ..  i.e   1 x 2

Shift it twice to multiply/divide by 4,   3 times for 8,  4 times for 16, etc...

It's not used overly frequently, but in cases like a physics engine port from C/C++, processing vast amounts of data, or some of the 3d engines, we'll see shifts as a remenant of the original code, or simply for speed.

(You might see it on some J2ME mobile java games too for example, where floating point units aren't available i.e.  shift a value left 10 bits so the remaining 10 bits acts like a kind of decimal point.. then shift it back for the real value when drawing to screen position, at the cost of the overall possible size)

The other use as mentioned is for a quick Math.floor();  -  but with a key differernce.
I did some benchmarks a few months back working with Box2D and found it hundreds of times quicker - odd since I assume both conversions are handled natively.

When rounding negative numbers,
Math.floor(-7.6) = -8
and
(-7.6 <<0  ) = -7

I.e.  <<0 on a Number (float) will round in the direction of 0.

Answer (score 8):

Number to integer conversion
Using int(x) is 10% faster in AS3. Still the bitwise version works better in AS2.

x = int(1.232)

//equals:
x = 1.232 >> 0;

best explained:http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/05/10/bitwise-gems-fast-integer-math/das

Comment: That link is giving me a 404.

Answer (score 4):

It might be a trick to get rid of the decimals without the overhead of a call to Math.floor() since even with a Number as input you will get an integer back.

I'm not sure how this compares performance wise to doing a (more commonly seen) cast to int(x)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you'll see this in an enum just for completeness, i.e.

```
flag0 = 1 >> 0,
flag1 = 1 >> 1,
flag2 = 1 >> 2
```

and so on. If you encounter this in code, I would expect that it is just some leftover from when there was actually more to shift (testing, changed requirements). That is, of course, unless this operator is not a shift operator in AS3. In C++, for example, it is also used as input stream operator (you know, because you're shifting some input into some variable. Sigh).

Comment: >> is definitely a bitshift operator in AS3

Comment: Did you mean left-shift (`<<`)?

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur: Would make more sense, wouldn't it? But then, the question was about `>>` ;)